# Installing mod_wsgi module for apache

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

WHEN I WAS INSTALLING WSGI MODULE FOR APACHE

I downloaded the module from `http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so`

Renamed it to `mod_wsgi.so`

Copied it to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules`

edited `httpd.conf` in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf`

Added line `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` in the module loading section of `httpd.conf`

restarted Apache

Apache cannot be restarted

The error in errorlog is:

```
Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

It is not an issue with file extension or permission.
Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

1. That you don't have extensions hidden and have added the extension twice.
2. That the mod_wsgi.so file is readable to whatever Apache service user is.
3. That your Apache is 32 bit.
4. That your Python is 32 bit.
5. That your Python is installed for all users and not just user you installed it as.

Comment: I have configured wsgi module. then

Comment: My extensions are not hidden; there are no doubled extensions, everything is 64 bit for me and Python is installed for all users. However, I still get the error "The specified module could not be found".

Comment: @TomJoy  I have wamp 32bit which uses 32 bit apache server, python is 32 bit. Still am not able to  run wamp server

Comment: I think even if WSGI is 64 bit and apache is 32 bit, it should not raise the error "The specified module could not be found" because this is misleading log info. Rather it should say "module is not compatible". Period.