# Apache error when installing mod_wsgi on windows: specified module could not be found

Tags: apache, windows-xp, mod-wsgi, python-2.6

I am getting the apache error:

```
Cannot load C:/ms4w/Apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found
```

I searched on the web already, and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447094/installing-mod-wsgi-module-for-apache) and I think I tried most of what is described in here, and my installation is still not working, so I think I need a bit of help.

- I run **windows XP 32bit** pro SP3, freshly installed on a VM
- I am running **python 2.6** which I downloaded [here](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6/python-2.6.msi)
- I am trying to install **mod_wsgi 3.3 for python 2.6**, which I downloaded [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.3.so)
- Python is installed for all users
- I run apache 2.2.22, as part of [ms4w package](http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=downloads.html)
- My file name is correct ( mod_wsgi.so )
- My LoadModule entry is:  `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`

If I comment my LoadModule line apache is running great. Python is working too.

However, I am not sure how to verify that apache's user is able to read the module on windows XP.

I don't know what else to try, thanks in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: Are you sure you have a 'module' directory. Normally it is 'modules'. Plural!

Comment: Sorry it's modules, I made a typo

Answer (score 0):

hope you might have got your issue resolved. if not there's a [very easy **tutorial**](http://abbett.org/post/setting-up-mod-wsgi-on-wampserver) I'd like to suggest, however this is using wampserver.

some points that needs to be considered:
download mod_wsgi version **compatible** to the wampserver's **apache & python version**

I've installed the latest wamp with **apache 2.4 & python 2.7 32 bit** so I got the mod_wsgi from [**here.**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)

hope it helps.